# Прописать веб страницы в spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Помогите настроить спринг так, чтобы  страница `index.jsp` (стартовая) запускалась не сама по себе, а ее запускал контроллер, потому что, мне бы хотелось передавать в нее различные значения.

Я пробовал ее перекладывать в специальную папку, которую сканирует класс `InternalResourceViewResolver` и добавлял в контроллере скажем такой метод:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Но в таком случае складывается такая ситуация, что все работает пока запущено на IDE, но если запускать напрямую из контейнера (у меня томкат). То начинаются ошибки путей. Т.к. в первом случае такой путь: `localhost/index.jsp`, а во втором такой: `localhost/spring/index.jsp`,  но страницы пытаются грузится по первому пути.

Причем такой ошибки нет, когда `index.jsp` лежит в корне и запускается сам по себе.

Comment: Развертывайте на томкате ваше приложение, как ROOT.war и тогда пути будут как в IDE

Comment: в путях не должно быть никакого локалхоста

Comment: Согласен, был пробел в моих знаниях. При развертывании как ROOT.war  проблема пропадает. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Nofate Как мне кажется, стоит опубликовать ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы его можно было принять.